# Not able to get aws resources through python

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

```
[root@localhost Desktop]# python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Sep 15 2016, 22:37:39) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import boto3
>>> s3=boto3.resources('s3')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe reading the documentation wouldn't do any harm. You can find this [here](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html). It shows you how to create a client for each service available in boto3 as well as how to call that service's operations.

Try the following:

```
# Import the boto3 library
import boto3

# Create a client that can access S3 on your behalf using your Access key and Secret key
client = boto3.client(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id=YOUR_ACCESS_KEY,
    aws_secret_access_key=YOUR_SECRET_KEY
)

# Example operation

response = client.list_objects(
    Bucket='YOUR_BUCKET_NAME'
)

print response
```

Answer (score 1):

`reources` is a module, `resource` is a function which is the one you are looking for.

```
>>> boto3.resources
<module 'boto3.resources' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto3/resources/__init__.pyc'>
>>> boto3.resource
<function resource at 0x7fbf18615410>
>>> from boto3 import resources
```

So, you should call `resource`

```
s3=boto3.resource('s3')
```